# Memory leak with preg_replace

Tags: php, regex, memory-leaks

I'm using the `preg_replace` function to replace accents in a string, I'm working with UTF-8.

I have incurred in what seems to be a memory leak, but I can't isolate the root cause, my code is rather simple:

```
    preg_replace(
        array_keys($aToNoAccents),
        array_values($aToNoAccents),
        $sText
    );
```

where `$aToNoAccents` is an associative array with entries like `'~[Ą]~u' => 'A', '~[Ć]~u' => 'C',`.
My script prints this error for the above line:

```
Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 1073741824 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 3039 bytes)
```

Obviously it's not a matter of increasing the allowed memory for PHP, (a 1Gb footprint is way off the scale of my application). Also, that line is executed thousands of times without problems but, just for some cases which are difficult to reproduce, it yields the error.

Is anyone aware of memory problems with preg_replace and UTF-8 strings?
Am I to use special care in passing actual parameters to such function?

I'm using PHP 5.2.6-3 with Suhosin-Patch

Comment: Are those regexps? Otherwise you should probably use `str_replace` instead and see if that works better?

Comment: Yes, maybe I don't need them to be regex after all. I'm giving it a try

Comment: PHP 8.1 and still a problem :(

Answer (score 3):

Have you tried [iconv](http://de.php.net/manual/en/function.iconv.php) instead of handcrafting your replacement map?

Adapting the example from PHP manual

```
$text = "A String with lots of weird chars, like ĄĆ";

echo 'Original : ', $text, PHP_EOL;
echo 'TRANSLIT : ', iconv("UTF-8", "ISO-8859-1//TRANSLIT", $text), PHP_EOL;
echo 'IGNORE   : ', iconv("UTF-8", "ISO-8859-1//IGNORE", $text), PHP_EOL;
echo 'Plain    : ', iconv("UTF-8", "ISO-8859-1", $text), PHP_EOL;
```

would yield

```
Original : A String with lots of weird chars, like AC
TRANSLIT : A String with lots of weird chars, like AC
IGNORE   : A String with lots of weird chars, like AC
Plain    : A String with lots of weird chars, like AC
```

But this does not necessarily would work with any chars you throw in. Give it a try with your desired keys.

Comment: That would be a good idea, but unfortunately for some countries I need to have full control over which character is translated to which, so I can't use an external tool for that task.

Answer (score 1):

i had same problem (memory leak) not with preg_replace and i "heard" that probably its a bug in php 5.2

I am not sure but if you try the same script with php 5.0 might work.

Just for the record.

Comment: Yeah, can you add a link here that leads to the bug?

Comment: There's a writeup here that suggests preg_replace caches up to 4096 results in a request: http://blog.killtheradio.net/tricks-hacks/phps-preg-functions-dont-release-memory/